# How to transform position of y axis in A-Frame 0.8.0?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to animate this vase so it just rotates in place around its y axis, but it's doing that while moving in a circle, leading me to believe that I need to move the anchor's position (wish I knew how). You can see the VR scene [here](http://chemical-opinion.glitch.me). Here's my code for this rotating asset:

```
<a-entity position=".7 1 -3">
          <a-gltf-model id="testvase1" rotation = "0 0 0" scale=".05 .05 .05"
                       src="#gltf" position="-.08 0 -.005">
          </a-gltf-model>
           <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="10000" 
                       from= "0 0 0" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>    
        </a-entity>
```

Full code available [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/chemical-opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

Don't translate your object to rotate around the center.

```
<a-entity position="0 0 0">
  <a-gltf-model id="testvase1" rotation = "0 0 0" scale="2 2 2" src="#gltf" position="0 0 0"></a-gltf-model>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="10000" from= "0 0 0" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>    
</a-entity>
```

Your models are not centered in the origin of coordinates. You will need to import in a 3d package like blender and re export centered. This is an example with your code and a model that is centered: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/utopian-walleye?path=public/index.html:32:19